# Outlook 2007 delayed email timestamp shows creation time

Tags: outlook, timestamp, delay, outlook-2007

I have some emails set up to be send lates. I used Outlook 2007 and "do no deliver until" feature. Problem is that when user gets email, the timestamp shows creation time, not the actual sending time. Is there any way to change this?

Answer (score 1):

I found it will not work if Outlook is not in Cache mode. After going to file, Account settings pull down, Account Settings, highlighting my account and choosing change, checked "Use Cached Exchange Mode", next, then finished fixed the problem. Now time stamp is when it leaves the outbox not when I push send.

Answer (score 0):

["Send Time" time stamp information is incorrect when you send a delayed delivery message in Outlook](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/247176)

"When you use Microsoft Outlook to send a delayed message, the actual "Sent Time" time stamp information for that message is the compose time of the message and not the actual sent time. **This is by design.**"

"When Outlook is connected in Online mode to an Exchange Server mailbox, the messages are directly submitted to the Exchange mailbox. Therefore, the "Sent Time" time stamp information for that message is the time that the message was submitted to the mailbox on Exchange, not the actual time that it was delivered to the recipient."